# Is it possible to query 'less than' in Apollo client of GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

With Apollo client we can query with variables like `id: $int` then, is it possible like `where: { expire_ls: $Int }` ?

Comment: I think it would be best to have an optional second variable you can take in where you can set the search parameters (so, (id: $int, expire_ls: $Int), and the resolver will do the rest of the work for you.  Resolvers (front or back-end) are what do the true workload to filter information.  GraphQL is just pushing the parameter inputs, and spitting the data back out in a readable form.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to filter with javascript method to do so.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the client. If the server and its schema support this condition field, then you can also use it with Apollo Client.

Answer (score -1):

For the future viewer, this might help:

```
{
  "sort": "_ID_ASC",
  "filter": {
    "_operators": {
      "_id": {
        "lt": "59c078e38abc06675f9d2ec2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```